# What does inflator.context() mean?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

What does `inflator.context()` mean in this line of code?

```
ArrayAdapter<DataType> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DataType>(
inflator.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It basically provides the context of the system inflator which inflates the given list item layout.

You can also use getActivity() if it's  inside a fragment and getContex() or 'this' if it's inside an activity.

Comment: what does inflator means

Comment: Every view inside android is in an xml. So basically to make this jargon into a visible layout, you have to inflate it. This is done by the inflator system service. Kind of like pop-up cards, when you open it, the view pops into display. This is what exactly the inflator is meant to do, convert jargon into ui